# Why does np.corrcoef() normalise to unity?

Tags: python, numpy

I feel like this is a stupid question, but the site of np.corrcoef(),

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html

states that it returns C_ij/sqrt{C_iiC_jj}, which means that

```
print(np.corrcoef(np.identity(5)))
```

Should just return the identity matrix. But instead, it returns

```
[[ 1.   -0.25 -0.25 -0.25 -0.25]
[-0.25  1.   -0.25 -0.25 -0.25]
[-0.25 -0.25  1.   -0.25 -0.25]
[-0.25 -0.25 -0.25  1.   -0.25]
[-0.25 -0.25 -0.25 -0.25  1.  ]]
```

so this function does normalize each row to 1. Why does this function claim to return C_ij/sqrt{C_iiC_jj}?

Thanks for the quick answers... just in case somebody makes the same mistake, the correct function is here

```
from statsmodels.stats.moment_helpers import cov2corr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you're misreading describes the relationship between a correlation coefficient matrix and a *covariance matrix*, not the relationship between `numpy.corrcoef`'s output and input.

If you were to compare `numpy.corrcoef(numpy.identity(5))` and `numpy.cov(numpy.identity(5))`, you would see the relationship you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

From the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L2463-L2544) you can see that first `numpy.cov` is called on the input. *After* that the normalization is done.

```
c = cov(x, y, rowvar)
# ...
d = diag(c)
# ...    
stddev = sqrt(d.real)
c /= stddev[:, None]
c /= stddev[None, :]
# ...
return c
```

So the "C" in the documentation does *not* refer to the input of the function, but to the intermediate result.